# exact angle between the functions $p(x)=3x-4$ and $q(x)=9x-5$ over $0\leq x\leq 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, functions

I was attempting a question, which gave the formula for the angle theta between two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ over $a\leq x\leq b$
(note the question defined the meaning of norm and inner product as these were concepts introduced in the question and previously unfamiliar to candidates, as they were not strictly taught/defined in the curriculum):

$$~\cos(\theta) = \dfrac{{\langle f, g\rangle}_{a}^{b}}{{\|f\|}_{a}^{b}.{\|g\|}_{a}^{b}}~$$

The question required me to find the exact angle between the functions $p(x)=3x-4$ and $q(x)=9x-5$ over $0\leq x\leq 1$

carrying out the steps and finding $\theta$ gave me an answer of $\theta= \pi/3$ (which is consistent with the answer on the mark scheme)

when I sketched the functions , the curves intersect at $x=1/6$ and form a much smaller angle than $\pi/3$, roughly about $15^o$

so i went back and attempted the question using the formula for angle of intersection between two curves $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$:

$$\tan\theta=\tan(\theta_1-\theta_2)=\frac{\tan\theta_1-\tan\theta_2}{1+\tan\theta_1*\tan\theta_2}$$

substuting values of $dy/dx$ for respective $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ we get:
$$\theta=12.1^o $$

I'm confused here, as I am unfamiliar with the $cos(\theta)$ formula, why do these methods give different answers?? also why does sketching the curves show a much smaller angle of intersection than $60^o$ as obtained by the method described in the original question.

Comment: In the first case, you are finding the angle between these two functions regarded as vectors in the vector space of continuous functions on [0,1].  In the second case, you are finding the angle between these two lines in the xy-plane. (Notice that the first angle makes sense even if the functions have graphs that do not intersect in the interval [0,1].)